# Gitlab repository size too big compared to its folder size

Tags: git, gitlab, git-remote, invisible

I have a Gitlab repository which shows too big size in Gitlab while its sum of existing files in the repo is a lot less:
[Gitlab repo size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt5iJ.png)

Gitlab repository shows around 700MB of storage and files while local git repo shows around 1MB:
[Local repo size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exk1i.png)

Local repository is up-to-date. However, when cloning the repo, it takes a long time until those 700MB are downloaded.

**Goal**: I need to get rid of the ghost files that is hidden but exists in the repo.

I already tried to search through Gitlab repo and local repo manually which did not give any results.

I also tried this script in git Bash:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | \
    sed -n $(git rev-list --objects --all | \
    cut -f1 -d' ' | \
    git cat-file --batch-check | \
    grep blob | \
    sort -n -k 3 | \
    tail -n40 | \
    while read hash type size; do 
         echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size/p ";
    done) | \
    sort -n -k1
```

And it gave me the following result:[Git Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmWZ.png)

"sound-controller.rar" file is not visible in the file explorer and GitLab repo. Therefore, I gave no idea how to remove that file. "git rm sound-controller" did not work.